# How do I pass multiple variables to other model like a variable in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, parallax

I make 1 page parallax site with MCV Model and i want to send all of data of pages to index_view `load->view($filename,$data);` as 1 `$data`. I can send all data as `load->view($filename,$data_index,$data_about,$data_services,$data_contact);` But I think that the way isn't good way. I want to show may site structure.

I have Index_model.php (Model), index.php (Controller) and index_view.php (view) files.

There are navigation Links and index page slogan text functions in Index_model.php:

```
public function nav(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM nav";
    $sth = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM nav");
    return $sth;
}

public function slogan()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM slogan";
    $row = $this->db->select($sql);
    return $row;
}
```

Index.php (Controller) page so that..

```
public function Index(){
    // Include Index_Model
    $index_model = $this->load->model("index");
    // Call Navigation Links functions
    $nav = $index_model->nav();

    $default = $this->defaults();
    // Call slogans
    $slogan = $index_model->slogan();
    $this->load->view('index', $nav, $default);
}
```

and View part of Load.php is so..

```
public function view($filename,$data = false, $default = false){
    include('app/view/'.$filename."_view.php");
}
```

How can i send my all value to view with 1 $variable.
Is it possible. How is made Parallax site in MVC model?

Comment: So you are using codeigniter ? . if yes you can use the `HMVC extension` , which allows you to call different modules with different methods and get their content without passing through load->view(); check this link for [HMVC EXTENSION](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

Comment: No i don't use codeigniter.

Comment: if i learn autoload function can i do that with autoload?

Comment: Then you have to specify , which kind of framework you are using, as if it's custom thing , then you should better know how it is working. Autoload has nothing to do with passing the content.

Comment: I don't use any framework. It is my spesific framework.

Comment: I  can recommend you to , not pass the data trough the view , just create the methods and then learn a bit about HMVC and how it works , Create modules type structure and use that. Then you will have all of your methods / widgets , everything better organised inside it's own controllers and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the variables in another array and pass the new array. like this

```
public function Index(){
    // Include Index_Model
    $index_model = $this->load->model("index");
    // Call Navigation Links functions
    $nav = $index_model->nav();

    $default = $this->defaults();
    // Call slogans
    $slogan = $index_model->slogan();
    $data=[];
    $data['nav']=$nav;
    $data['default']=$default;
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```